# Apps built with VS2017 in C++ in Release mode do not break on unhandled exception

Tags: c++, exception, x86, visual-studio-2017

This question refers to native C++ programs built by VS2017 but executed OUTSIDE of the VS IDE:

Why unhandled exceptions are silently ignored in native C++ Release builds, while Debug builds catch the same exception and display the nice expected error message ?

I tried finding the build setting, that affects the unhandled Exeptions but failed.

The code that generates the exception is listed below.
Note, that I am not asking how to fix this code and avoid the exception (or how to handle it), but how to **unignore** this exception in Release builds, so the OS catches it and complains.

```
std::map<const string, const int> MyMap;

auto it = MyMap.find("Cant Find Me");
int res = it->second; //Dereferencing the end iterator causes the expected exception. This exception is not explicitly handled anywhere else.
```

In response to some comments about Debug Assertion vs. Exception I have tried it with the following exception provoking code:

```
PCHAR p;
p = NULL;
*p = 'X';  //Provoke an exception by following a null pointer and awaiting the chaos and madness at its end...
```

This code still does not provoke any error messages when executed OUTSIDE of the MSVC IDE. This happens for BOTH the Release and Debug builds, now.

Comment: Q: So you're saying the application is an .exe, and that it doesn't crash with an exception when you run it outside of MSVS (e.g., run it from a command prompt)?

Comment: Exactly...but the same application built in Debug mode crashes nicely.

Comment: Dereferencing an `end()` iterator is undefined behavior. Why do you think it's required to throw an exception?

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson *but the same application built in Debug mode crashes nicely* -- That is because the VS debug runtime uses "checked iterators", meaning iterator values are checked (and that also means your program runs slower).  There is no such iterator checks in release mode.  Also, what you are seeing in the debug build is an`assert()` dialog, not an exception being thrown, not a crash.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie: You are correct, the error is an Assertion - not an exception. I have to agree with you, that this message is caused by the debug runtime library used in Debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereferencing the end iterator is *undefined behaviour*. An implementation is permitted to do what it pleases.

In debug builds, your particular implementation translates this to a nice user friendly error with a human readable message. This is a debugging aid.

In release builds, it does not, because release builds are not meant for debugging. Leaving debugging code in would hurt overall performance.

Addendum. It looks like your analysis of the situation with the first code fragment is as follows.

1. Dereferencing an end iterator normally causes a CPU exception.
2. The release build actively silences said exception.
3. The debug build leaves the exception handled as per the OS default, which causes termination with a nice error message.

This analysis is incorrect. What in happens is as follows:

1. Dereferencing the end iterator is *undefined behaviour*. An implementation is permitted to do what it pleases.
2. In the release build, dereferencing an end iterator does not cause a CPU exception or any other immediately catchable error, as is normal for many mainstream implementations of `std::string` on the x86 architecture
3. In the debug build, the implementation actively causes the program to raise a user-friendly exception upon dereferencing an end iterator, for a price of reduced performance.

As for the second code fragment, it may or may not cause a CPU exception, and a CPU exception may or may not cause a user-friendly error message. The behaviour of it is *undefined*. It isn't quite clear why you decided that (1) an exception does happen, and (2) it is being silently ignored by an implementation. There is absolutely no evidence that would suggest that. If a CPU exception does happen, the application probably just abnormally terminates without any user-visible error message. Your IDE, having included a debugger, is able to catch the abnormal termination and translate it to a user-friendly error, even for a release build. Outside of the IDE you are on your own.

Comment: ...but when I purposely dereference a null pointer, the program still does not provoke any error messages when executed OUTSIDE of the MSVC IDE.

Comment: That's because undefined behaviour is not tied to the IDE, it's a C/C++ concept.

Comment: @Philipp:  I doubt that dereferencing a null pointer is an "undefined behavior".

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson *An implementation is permitted to do what it pleases*. Providing debugging aids (only) with a tool meant for debugging is certainly one of the infinite number of things it is permutted to do.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson It very much is.

Comment: @n.m: is an Unhandled Exception (caused by the CPU accessing the Page 0 where the null pointer points) also an "undefined behavior" ?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is a term used by the C++ standard. There is no need to use quotation marks around it. It is a basic requirement for a C++ programmer to unserstand what it means. The standard doesn't talk about memory pages at all. The only exceptions the standard knows about are those raised by the `throw` operator (and by some library functions). If your implementation provides other kinds of exceptions, such as those raised by dereferencing a null pointer, then those are *by definition* undefined behaviour.

Comment: I was not asking what "undefined behavior" was, and I put it in quotes to delineate words that are not mine. I was asking whether the C++ can really do ANYTHING in response to an exception which is not explicitly handled by the C++ code ...such as handling the exception silently?  The CPU does jump to the OS' exception handler when it hits Page 0 - so what setting causes this implementation (MSVC 2017) to handle this exception internally in silence instead of  leaving it to the OS' default exception handler?

Comment: The answer to your question has to be no. Because again, if something invokes undefined behaviour you have no guarantee for what will happen and there are no assumptions to be made on how to 'handle' this. Only way to deal with this is to write code with defined behaviour - if we are talking about release builds.

Comment: So how do I prevent this implementation from silently handling the CPU exception (not a thrown C++ exception!) caused by dereferencing a null pointer (accessing Page 0) and allow the OS' Default Exception Handler to handle it ?

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson You don't dereference a null pointer, ever. Full stop, end of story.

Comment: @n.m: Of course, not on purpose, that was just a minimal verifiable example.  However, dereferencing a bad pointer can happen by accident and I don't want the CPU exception, that will be caused by it, to be silenced by C++ implementation.  I want all unhandled CPU exceptions to be handled by the OS' Default Exception Handler.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson There's no CPU exception, unhandled or otherwise, in your release build. Dereferencing an end iterator doesn't necessarily cause a CPU exception (strictly speaking, neither does dereferencing a null pointer, but that's a separate issue). Translating invalid iterator dereferences to CPU exceptions or any other kind of easily-catchable error is a *debugging aid*. Your debug build does that, your release build doesn't.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson I have expanded the answer with info from the comments.

Comment: @n.m: I always agreed with you that dereferencing an end-iterator doesn't necessarily cause a CPU exception, however accessing invalid memory by dereferencing e.g. a null pointer - DOES.  The C++ implementation cannot stop the latter CPU exception - it can only choose to handle it or not.  My latter question was how to stop it from handling it silently in MSVC2017 and leave it for the OS' Default Exception Handler to handle.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson No, not really. Let me repeat. *Dereferencing a null pointer doesn't necessarily cause a CPU exception*. [Here's a simple example of this](https://godbolt.org/z/Xw6lFQ). It is **undefined** and that's all that there's to know about it. However, if an exception does happen, it is quite unlikely that your implementation handles it on its own accord.